# How is AUC, Precision, Recall being calculated in this loop

Tags: python

This code block creates a dictionary of models and iterates through scoring and models creating three key value pairs.

The format identified by `{0},{1}` is mapped by the `eval()` method using `j` (the score values) and the `model_name` strings which are matched by `index` to the `model` names.

`{0}` is replaced by `j` and `{1}` is replaced by `model_name[model.index(i)]`.

Only the variables inside the string i.e. `{0}` and `{1}` are evaluated and extraneous characters that aren't a variable or operator i.e. `Mean_` and `_CV` is ignored. So how then are the actual `AUC`, `Precision` and `Recall` values calculated?

```
model = ['Logistic Regression','KNN','Gaussian NB','Decision Trees','Random Forest','Ensemble']
scoring = ['AUC','Precision','Recall']
model_name = ['Logit','KNN','NB','tree','forest','ensemble']
model_list = []

for i in model:
    for j in scoring: 
        model_dic = {'Model': i,'Scoring':j, 'Score':eval('Mean_{0}_{1}_CV'.format(j,model_name[model.index(i)]))}
        model_list.append(model_dic)
```

Output

```
# Model | Scoring | Score
# Logistic Regression   AUC 0.957516
# ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
model_dic = {'Model': i,'Scoring':j, 'Score':eval('Mean_{0}_{1}_CV'.format(j,model_name[model.index(i)]))}
```

This line does too much all at once. To understand what it is doing, break it into smaller pieces:

```
formatted = 'Mean_{0}_{1}_CV'.format(j,model_name[model.index(i)])
evaluated = eval(formatted)
model_dic = {'Model': i,'Scoring':j, 'Score':evaluated}
```

Now you can add `print()` statements to understand better what is happening:

```
formatted = 'Mean_{0}_{1}_CV'.format(j,model_name[model.index(i)])
print(formatted)
evaluated = eval(formatted)
print(evaluated)
model_dic = {'Model': i,'Scoring':j, 'Score':evaluated}
print(model_dic)
```

I suggest that you read about the `format()` and `eval()` functions to understand the output.

Comment: Thanks for the breakdown. What I didn't understand was where my actual AUC, Precision, Recall results were derived from in the project. But then your answer helped me spot the previous variables that were declared way up in the notebook such as `Mean_AUC_KNN_CV` and `Mean_Precision_KNN_CV`.   And your code is certainly a lot cleaner. Thanks!

Comment: @Edison This is still not the best way to solve the problem. Using `eval()` on a string is dangerous since it executes arbitrary code. There is probably a better way to do what this is trying to do, but I don't have enough information to suggest anything.

Comment: Most likely, you could put `Mean_AUC_KNN_CV` and the other variables in a list or dict to begin with